# Any way to deploy database in PhpStorm?

Tags: deployment, phpstorm

I can deploy files via FTP to the remote host. Is there any way to deploy database along with files? I use a CMS so when I change something in the control panel it'll be written to the db. I don't want to do double work or do it manually (it's buggy way, huh).

Comment: What database do you use? Usually you can't just copy the database files when the server is started, this problem is better addressed by setting up a database replication.

Comment: @CrazyCoder No, I don't want to copy the database files themselves. I want to run an SQL query on the remote or whatever. Copy some tables. You know, in Ruby we can migrate at least db structure. I can copy some SQL queries and run import on remote. If I only knew how to do this.

Comment: You can use the [database integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/data-sources-2.html), but you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm has a view 'Database' which can view all structure of your DB. Also you can run a SQL Script from local file to remote DB. Perhaps work with triggers etc...

[PHPStorm Database](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/sql-support-and-database-tools/)